# Can someone explain the solution to "If $x^2+ax−3x−(a+2)=0$ has real and distinct roots, then minimum value of $(a^2+1)/(a^2+2)$ is?"

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Could we not have directly skipped to the last line of the solution?
The conclusion seems disjointed from the previous lines.

**[Question]:**

If $x^2+ax−3x−(a+2)=0$ has real and distinct roots, then minimum value of $(a^2+1)/(a^2+2)$
is...?

**[Given Solution]:**

$x^2+ax−3x−(a+2)=0$

$D=(a−3)^2+4(a+2)$

$⇒D=a^2−2a+17$

$D1​=4−4(17)<0$

Therefore, $a^2−2a+17>0$ for all $a∈R$

Now, $(a^2+1)/(a^2+2)​=1−1/(a^2+2)​>1−(1/2)​=1/2 $

---

What exactly were we able to prove in those first 5 lines of the solution? At first I thought we had proven that 'a' would always be real and never complex, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Those steps are done to ensure that for all values of $a$, the equation will have distinct real roots. Suppose to have $D>0$, some restrictions on $a$ were to happen, then those would have reflected in the minimum value of the expression as well.

Comment: The first five lines purport to show that the roots are real and distinct for all choices of $a$.  I don't understand what $D1$ is, so I don't understand their argument.  But it is clear that $D=a^2-2a+17$ is always positive which is all you need.

Comment: @lulu I think $D1$ is the discriminant of the quadratic $a^2-2a+17$. Which ensures that this has no real root, hence $>0$.

Comment: @AnuragA but the questions specifically states "[The equation] has real and distinct roots". Why do we have to prove it again?

Comment: @AnuragA  Oh, of course.  Thanks.  Still, though, I think it is easier to just remark that $a^2-2a+17=(a-1)^2+16>>0$.  But this method works too.

Comment: @SelfishStoic What is given is the condition that the equation has real distinct roots **for some $a$**, and for those $a$ find the ….

Comment: If there were a possibility that $a$ could be complex, then a positive discriminant alone would not be enough to ensure that the roots of the quadratic are real. So, there's evidently an assumption here that $a$ must be real. Then, as has been noted in earlier comments, the argument shows that the discriminant is actually *always* positive (for real $a$), so that the problem reduces to minimizing $(a^2+1)/(a^2+2)$ over $\mathbb{R}$. The discriminant test was needed to ensure that there wasn't some limited range of viable $a$-values, which could have restricted viable $(a^2+1)/(a^2+2)$-values.

Comment: @SelfishStoic, please see my answer. Even though it's given in question that the equation has real and distinct roots. We have to find "conditions on $a$" for which we have to start from $D$. And as it turns out $D\gt 0$ and hence $a$ is real. So the first few lines are required to show that $a$ is real.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right, there are useless steps.

The minimum value of

$$\frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2}=1-\frac1{a^2+2}$$ is achieved by $a=0$, if this is an admissible value.

And indeed, $$\Delta(0)=0^2-2\cdot0+17>0$$

and we are done.

---

In fact the author was solving the inequation $a^2-2a+17>0$ to find the smallest admissible value of $a^2$ (corresponding to the smallest value of $|a|$), and concluded that $a\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x^2+ax−3x−(a+2)=0$ to have real and distinct roots, its discriminant $D$ must be strictly +ve. That is, we must have, $D\gt 0$, which is true because as you have rightly shown
$D=a^2−2a+17$ and since $D'=(2)^2-4(17)\lt 0$, We know that $ a^2-2a+17=0\implies$ the equation $D=0$ can not have any real root, that is $D\ne 0$ for any real $a$. In fact, $D=a^2-2a+17=(a-1)^2+16\gt 0 \;\;\forall a\in\mathbb R$. Therefore $a$ has to be real so that $D\gt 0$.

PS: 1) Geometrically, $D=a^2−2a+17$ represents a parabola on $D-a$ axis and since $D\gt 0$, it never intersects axis of $a$ and hence $D\ne 0$ rather $D\gt 0$. 
2) In the first five lines, we showed that $a$ is real.

Comment: Can 'D' not be positive for some complex/imaginary value of 'a'. If so, why?

Comment: Consider $ix^2 +2x +2i=0$. Clearly $D\gt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation $$x^2+ax−3x−(a+2)=0$$ is $-(a+2)$ the product of roots.
It is given that the roots are real, therefore $$a \;\text{is real.}$$
The answer to your question is YES: the first steps of the given solution can be skipped, we could go directly to the last line.